# How to start ODBC tracing without using Data Source Administrator?

Tags: java, database, cmd, odbc

we are working on a java 8 standalone project, and we need to extract a query log from another application (an .exe), **we were using the ODBC tracing to get the logs (manually for each run)**, but now **we need to get them automatically** (the other application querys variates depending of a .txt that we edit during the execution).

We need to know if there is a way to start the odbc tracing using java code, or with Runtime code (with cmd). What kind of alternatives we have?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `Trace` key value in the registry should start tracing. Be sure to turn it off when not needed. Here is a PowerShell script to do that.

```
Push-Location
Set-Location HKCU:\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC
Set-ItemProperty . Trace "1"
# Set-ItemProperty . TraceDll "C:\WINDOWS\system32\odbctrac.dll"
# Set-ItemProperty . TraceFile "$Env:USERPROFILE\SQL.LOG"
Pop-Location
```

If it must be run from a cmd.exe shell, put the script into traceon.ps1 and use the following command. If you have already configured your machine to be able to run PowerShell scripts, then the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` is not needed.

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File traceon.ps1
```